# Why does the behavior of chan change after I use gorm to connect to the database

Tags: go, go-gorm

A normal example is this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    ch := make(chan int)
    func() {
        time.Sleep(1)
        ch <- 1
    }()

    fmt.Println(<-ch)
}
```

The output should be:

```
# go run test.go
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [chan send]:
main.main.func1(...)
    /root/test.go:17
main.main()
    /root/test.go:18 +0x47
exit status 2
```

But when I add the code to connect to the database like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"

    "gorm.io/driver/mysql"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

func main() {
    db, err := gorm.Open(mysql.Open("dsn"))
    fmt.Printf("%v, %s\n", db, err)

    ch := make(chan int)
    func() {
        time.Sleep(1)
        ch <- 1
    }()

    fmt.Println(<-ch)
}
```

It doesn't report an error, it keeps blocking, the output is(I ended it with ctrl+c):

```
# go run test.go
&{0xc00015c510 <nil> 0 0xc00016c380 1}, %!s(<nil>)
^Csignal: interrupt
```

Can anyone help me, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It does not report `all goroutines are asleep` in case of connected DB because all goroutines are not asleep.

gorm and db start their own goroutines that are waiting to send receive, doing other stuff.

if you do a `ctrl+\` in both cases these goroutines will be shown

1 No DB connected

```
goroutine 0 [idle]: runtime.epollwait()
        /usr/lib/golang/src/runtime/sys_linux_amd64.s:699 +0x20 runtime.netpoll(0xc000032500?)
        /usr/lib/golang/src/runtime/netpoll_epoll.go:126 +0xdc
```

2. DB connected

```
goroutine 0 [idle]:
runtime.futex()
        /usr/lib/golang/src/runtime/sys_linux_amd64.s:552 +0x21
runtime.futexsleep(0x10000000000?, 0xcb927f8?, 0x7fffc45f8fa8?)
        /usr/lib/golang/src/runtime/os_linux.go:66 +0x36

goroutine 1 [chan send]:
main.main.func1(...)

goroutine 19 [select]:
database/sql.(*DB).connectionOpener(0xc00019ea90, {0x81af60, 0xc0001972c0})

goroutine 20 [select]:
github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql.(*mysqlConn).startWatcher.func1()
```